# How to operate on a column inside a pandas multi-index

Tags: python, pandas

In a pandas data frame, I want to add a column `var3` that is the minimum of an integer and column `var1`.
However, the column is part of a multi-index that I make with `unstack()`.

In isolation, I can call column `var1` with `df_wide['value']['var1']`.
However, I cannot perform the `np.min()` operation and generate the new column `var3`.

Is there a way I can strip all of these nested indexes to make pandas more like R?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df= pd.DataFrame()
month = np.arange(1, 13)
np.random.seed(42)
values1 = np.random.randint(0, 100, 12)
values2 = np.random.randint(200, 300, 12)

df['month'] = np.hstack((month, month))
df['variable'] = np.hstack((np.repeat('var1', 12), np.repeat('var2', 12)))
df['value'] = np.hstack((values1, values2))
df['year'] = 2020

print(df.head())

df.set_index(['year', 'month', 'variable'], inplace=True)
df_wide = df.unstack().reset_index()

print(df_wide.head())

df_wide['var3'] = np.min(25, df_wide['var1'])
```

Yields the following error: `TypeError: 'Series' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

Comment: Do you want to keep the nested indices going forward (and temporarily act as if they weren't nested), or do you want to undo the nesting itself?

Comment: @ASGM I am OK removing all indexes all the time. Coming from R and Stata, I find the multi-indexes a little confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`numpy.minimum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.minimum.html) and for select column in `MulitIndex` is possible use [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html):

```
df_wide['var3'] = np.minimum(25, df_wide.xs('var1', axis=1, level=1))
print(df_wide.head())
          year month value      var3
variable              var1 var2     
0         2020     1    51  223   25
1         2020     2    92  202   25
2         2020     3    14  221   14
3         2020     4    71  252   25
4         2020     5    60  201   25
```

But you can avoid `MulitIndex` here by specify column before `unstack` by select for `Series`:

```
df_wide = df.set_index(['year', 'month', 'variable'])['value'].unstack().reset_index()

df_wide['var3'] = np.minimum(25, df_wide['var1'])

print(df_wide.head())
variable  year  month  var1  var2  var3
0         2020      1    51   223    25
1         2020      2    92   202    25
2         2020      3    14   221    14
3         2020      4    71   252    25
4         2020      5    60   201    25
```

Comment: My major error was not recognizing that `np.min()` and `np.minimum()` are different functions. Thanks for the lesson on how to properly use unstack here!